# Transform matrix to one-line representation for copy&paste

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have an output which is a large array, say 500x4.
I would like to transform this array into code form to create the same array.
An example:

```
output_array = randn(2,3)
output_array =
   -0.2408   -0.9390    1.1794
   -0.9064    0.1178   -0.4643
```

I would like to obtain:

```
input_array = [-0.2408   -0.9390    1.1794; -0.9064    0.1178   -0.4643]
```

For low dimensions, manual work is easy, but I would to be able to obtain the input code for arbitrary matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you mean `output_array` and `input_array` are the same? Maybe it gets clearer if you tell us the purpose. What do you want to do with  `input_array`?

Comment: Yes they are the same array; suppose I have only the output of the matlab display and would like to obtain the code that inputs that same matrix.

Comment: so you would be happy with a string or char array as you want to copy&paste it?

Comment: I didnt understand; I want;
input_array = [-0.2408   -0.9390    1.1794; -0.9064    0.1178   -0.4643]

Comment: You can't an output like this, unless you output a string. That's why I'm asking what you need it for. Because if you want to copy&paste the output, it doesn't matter if its numeric or chars/string

Comment: Yes, I just want to copy and paste the output.

Comment: Why not simply use `save` and `load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
a = randi(2,3)

linespec = [repmat('%d ',1,size(a,2)) '; ']
spec = strrep(['[ ' repmat(linespec,1,size(a,1)) ' ]'],';  ','')
b = sprintf(spec,a(:) )
```

---

```
a =

     2     2     1
     1     1     1
     1     2     2


linespec =

%d %d %d ; 


spec =

[ %d %d %d ; %d %d %d ; %d %d %d ]


b =

[ 2 1 1 ; 2 1 2 ; 1 1 2 ]
```

Be aware, that the number of spaces defined in `' ... '` snippets do matter!

---

use:

```
spec = ['b = ' strrep(['[ ' repmat(linespec,1,size(a,1)) ' ]'],';  ','') ]
```

to get:

```
b =

b = [ 1 2 2 ; 1 2 2 ; 1 2 1 ]
```

---

It could be interesting to wrap everything into a function:

```
function [ out ] = Matrix2String( a )

varname = inputname(1);

linespec = [repmat('%d ',1,size(a,2)) '; '];
spec = [varname ' = ' strrep(['[ ' repmat(linespec,1,size(a,1)) ' ]'],';  ','') ];
out = sprintf(spec,a(:) );
end
```

a call like:

```
a = randi(2,3)
Matrix2String(a)
```

would then return:

```
ans =

a = [ 2 1 1 ; 2 1 2 ; 1 1 1 ]
```